# Representation of a number in a generic base

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I was just trying to write a simple function, that returns the representation of any number `z` that is passed in to it in base `k` that is also passed into it.

Thus far the function does what it is supposed to do but in reverse.

```
rep 0 _ = [0]
rep z k = (mod z k) : rep (floor (fromIntegral z / fromIntegral k) ) k
```

There is also a (leading, but now trailing 0), but this is not too important right now. So for example `rep 1 2` will result in `[1,0]`, but it should result in `[0,1]`.

Another example: `rep 8 2` should create `[0,1,0,0]` which would be fine, but it does create `[0,0,1,0]`. I also think the problem is that `:`appends to the front of the list. I rather should swap the code to:

```
rep z k =rep (floor (fromIntegral z / fromIntegral k) ) k : (mod z k)
```

or with brackets

```
rep z k =(rep (floor (fromIntegral z / fromIntegral k) ) k) : (mod z k)
```

But neither one works as it gets infinite.

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ [t]
Relevant bindings include
k :: [t] (bound at knaerBasis.hs:3:7)
z :: [t] (bound at knaerBasis.hs:3:5)
rep :: [t] -> [t] -> [t] (bound at knaerBasis.hs:1:1)
In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely
‘(rep (floor (fromIntegral z / fromIntegral k)) k)’
In the expression:
(rep (floor (fromIntegral z / fromIntegral k)) k) : (mod z k)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 4):

The type of `rep` is `rep :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> [a]`), but the type of `mod z k` is just `a`. Thus you should write

```
(rep (floor ...)) ++ [mod z k]
```

as the type of `(:)` is `a -> [a] -> [a]`, while `(++)` has type `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

Another reasonable alternative is to just call `reverse` on the resulting list!

Comment: Uhm... do you mean `++ [mod z k]` instead of `:[mod z k]`? The latter does not look well-typed.

Comment: @chi Fixed. Keep me on my toes!

Comment: `++ [...]` is very inefficient compared to `reverse`ing at the end.

Comment: Yeah, concatentation is O(n^2) while reversing at the end keeps the whole function O(n).

Answer (score 3):

The quickest fix is to just apply `reverse` on the result:

```
rep :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
rep a = reverse . rep' a
    where rep' 0 _ = [0]
          rep' z k = (z `mod` k) : rep' (z `div` k) k
```

Your previous `(floor (fromIntegral z / fromIntegral k) )` has also been refactored to the equivalent expression `(div z k)`.

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb36d545f93252c5)

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at `showIntAtBase` from `Numeric`. Here is the source: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Numeric.html#showIntAtBase